# Joining data by 'rbind' as a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have two equally long dataset - 'vpXmin' and 'vpXmax' created from 'vp'

```
> head(vpXmin)
                 vp
[1,] 253641 2621722
[2,] 253641 2622722
[3,] 253641 2623722
[4,] 253641 2624722
[5,] 253641 2625722
[6,] 253641 2626722

> head(vpXmax)
                 vp
[1,] 268641 2621722
[2,] 268641 2622722
[3,] 268641 2623722
[4,] 268641 2624722
[5,] 268641 2625722
[6,] 268641 2626722
```

I want to join each of the rows from these datasets using 'rbind' and want to create separate matrix; e.g.

```
l1<-rbind(vpXmax[1,],vpXmin[1,])
l2<-rbind(vpXmax[2,],vpXmin[2,])
 ... ...
```

Even though I'm not familiar with R loops, I want to deal with such a large data as a loop ... but I failed while trying this:

```
for (i in 1:length(vp)){rbind(vpXmax[i,],vpXmin[i,])}
```

Any idea why? Also, please gimme some good references for learning different kinds of loops using R, if any. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(head(vpXmax))` and `dput(head(vpXmin))`. Also, do you want a separate matrix for *each* row? Please post a sample of your desired output to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: When you say "I failed...", please describe exactly what happened!  Did you get an error message?  The first thing I notice is that you're not assigning the result of `rbind` to a variable: it looks like your loop will do all the calculations but throw away the result.

Comment: What was your error in the for loop? You will need to make an assignment in each loop e.g. `l[[i]] <- rbind(vpXmax[i,],vpXmin[i,])`. Note that for loops are not the usual or idiomatic way to do what you seem to be doing.

Comment: There was no ERROR for the 'for loop' in the console!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
vpXmax <- matrix(1:10,ncol=2)
vpXmin <- matrix(11:20,ncol=2)

l <- lapply(1:nrow(vpXmin),function(i) rbind(vpXmax[i,],vpXmin[i,]) )
```

Then, instead of `l1`, `l2` etc etc you have

```
l[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    6
#[2,]   11   16
l[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    7
#[2,]   12   17
```

And although it is probably not ideal, there is one major thing wrong with your initial loop.
You aren't assigning your output, so you need to use `assign` or `<-` in some way to actually make an object. However, using `assign`, is pretty much a flag to set off alarm bells that there is a better way to do things, and `<-` would require pre-allocating or other stuffing around.
Nevertheless, it will work, albeit polluting your work space with `l1` `l2`... `ln` objects:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(vpXmax)) {assign(paste0("l",i), rbind(vpXmax[i,],vpXmin[i,]) )}

> l1
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    6
#[2,]   11   16

> l2
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    7
#[2,]   12   17
```

Comment: Thanks, but my final goal is to make each of these objects into spatial lines. So I used "lapply" to do so as: L1<-lapply(1:length(l),function(i) Line(l[[i]])) ...
Ls1<-lapply(1:length(L1),function(i) Lines(list(L1[[i]]), ID="a")) ... 
SL1<-lapply(1:length(Ls1),function(i) SpatialLines(list(Ls1[[i]]))) ... but I just can't unlist SL1 (class: spatial line) before plotting (plot(SL1)) to avoid the error: 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'.

Answer (score 0):

As @ToNoy indicates, it is not obvious the kind of output that you want. The easiest way to proceed would be to create a list in which each element is the result of `rbind` each row of the two original data frames.

```
A <- data.frame("a" = runif(100, -1, 0), "b" = runif(100, 0, 1))                                                                                                                     
Z <- data.frame("a" = runif(100, -2, -1), "b" = runif(100, 1, 2))                                                                                                                    

output <- vector("list", nrow(A))                                                                                                                                                    
for (i in 1:nrow(A)) {                                                                                                                                                               
    output[[i]] <- rbind(A[i, ], Z[i, ])                                                                                                                                             
}
```